# multiprecision unsigned subtraction in C

Tags: c, integer-arithmetic, modular-arithmetic, multiprecision

I am trying to implement multi-precision unsigned subtraction over a finite field (p=2^191-19) in C, but I cannot figure out how to deal with borrow bit!
My operands are represented in radix-2^16 as:

```
typedef unsigned long long T[12];
```

which means each element of the T-type array has exactly 16-bits data (radix-2^16 representation). 
Now I want to subtract two operands of T type, but I do not know which one is smaller! If the result is negative, I want to add the result to the prime value to have positive results in modular arithmetic. 
Here is my implementation based on [this](http://diamond.boisestate.edu/~liljanab/MATH308/GuideToECC.pdf) book page-30(Multiprecision subtraction algorithm):

```
void bigint192_sub(T r, const T a, const T b){
    int i;
    int borrow;
    r[0] = a[0] - b[0];
    borrow = r[0] >> 16;
    r[0] &= 0xFFFF;
    for(i=1;i<12;++i){
        r[i] = a[i] - b[i] - borrow;
        borrow = r[i] >> 16;
        r[i] &= 0xFFFF;
    }
}
```

but I got the wrong answer!

```
My inputs:
a =0x2d7e33e5bba0f6bb87ce04b28e940662db8f3f81aaf94576
b =0x28afc585dca4a8003b081f7289de11c2d229d5a967081f72
Myresult=0x4d16e62defd4ebc4cc8e54104b7f4a0096769d843f12604
Crresult=0x4ce6e5fdefc4ebb4cc5e54004b5f4a0096569d843f12604
```

Comment: What were your inputs, your expected output, and actual output?

Comment: This looks wrong. Wouldn't you borrow from `0x10000` if `a[i]` is less than `b[i]`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I put a reference in my question. I know it seems wired to me as well, but it's exactly the way that shows in the book!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fix `borrow` evaluation, since it may be only `0` or `1`. So you should treat underflow as `borrow` equals to `1`:

```
borrow = (r[i] >> 16) != 0;
```

Also I'd rewrite function in a bit more general form, since we may treat first pass as like we have no borrow:

```
void bigint192_sub(T r, const T a, const T b){
    int i;
    int borrow;
    for (borrow = 0, i = 0; i < 12; ++i) {
        r[i] = a[i] - b[i] - borrow;
        borrow = (r[i] >> 16) != 0;
        r[i] &= 0xFFFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: you could also write `borrow = (r[i] >> 16) != 0; // no need for trick comment`

Comment: @Darklighter Oh, yes, it is even simpler. Thanks!